# iPhone - Facebook issue with ShareKit

Tags: iphone, facebook, sharekit

I am using the below code to integrate facebook sharing in my iPhone App. It works fine most of the time. But some times instead of showing a login window , it displays a blank window and nothing is displayed in that. So user fails to share it on Facebook. I don't know whats going wrong !!

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.socialdealspot.com"];
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem URL:url title:deal.title];
item.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon.PNG"];
SHKActionSheet *actionSheet = [SHKActionSheet actionSheetForItem:item];

// Display the action sheet
[actionSheet showFromToolbar:self.navigationController.toolbar];
```

Has anyone faced this issue before or I am doing something wrong .Please help me !!

I am able to post the first time I logs in. After wards when I try to share something it just displays a blank screen . . . ? Can Any body please look into this . . ??

Thank You !!

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me with Sharekit for about 5 hours on July 3. I chose to wait it out and it fixed itself. Must have been a serverside issue maybe?

Comment: yes , sometimes it gives blank page , sometimes it works properly !! What can be the cause ?. Even if it is server fault , it should display that error or some alert or something ...

Comment: I am able to post the first time I logs in. After wards when I try to share something it just displays a blank screen . . . ? Can Any body please look into this . . ??