# What's wrong with my sharing method on Facebook?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, youtube, sharekit

After I successfully upload my test video on youtube, I try to share it on Facebook with ShareKit.

```
- (void)shareFBVideo {
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem URL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.youtubeLink] 
                         title:@"Link :video only for test."];
item.text = @"share text";
[SHKFacebook shareItem:item];
}
```

Everything is fine, but on my wall I see: [image] 
Can you explain what this encoding mean, and how to remove it?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want an image to display instead off that encoding?
In this case, please look at the following :
[iPhone - Facebook issue with ShareKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608530/iphone-facebook-issue-with-sharekit)

Otherwise, i can't help.
I'm sorry.